# Erro Jogo da Serpente em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um exercício em javascript de criação do jogo da serpente acompanhando um [vídeo no Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hua1OSXitdQ).
O erro que está dando é que os quadrados que compõem a serpente estão aparecendo separados e piscando por todo o espaço da tela. rs
Já revisei o código e não consigo encontrar o erro, alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
window.onload = function() {
    //Criando elementos 2d no canvas
    var stage = document.getElementById('stage')
    var ctx = stage.getContext("2d")

    document.addEventListener("keydown", KeyPush)
    setInterval(game, 80)
    const vel = 1
    var velocidadex = 0
    var velocidadey = 0
    var cabecax = 10
    var cabecay = 15
    var tamanhop = 30
    var quantidadep = 20
    var frutax = 15
    var frutay = 15
    var rastro = []
    rabo = 5

    function game() {
    cabecax += velocidadex
    cabecay += velocidadey

    //Movimento da cobra ao bater nas bordas
    if (cabecax < 0){
        cabecax = quantidadep - 1
    }
    if (cabecax > quantidadep - 1) {
        cabecax = 0
    }
    if (cabecay < 0){
        cabecay = quantidadep - 1
    }
    if (cabecay > quantidadep - 1) {
        cabecay = 0
    }

    //Plano de fundo
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,128,128)"
    ctx.fillRect(0,0, stage.width, stage.height)
    //Fruta
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(173,255,47)"
    ctx.fillRect(frutax*tamanhop, frutay*tamanhop, tamanhop, tamanhop)
    //Cobra
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,182,193)"
    for(var i = 0; i < rastro.length; i++){
        ctx.fillRect(rastro[i].x*tamanhop, rastro[i].y*tamanhop, tamanhop-1, tamanhop-1)
        //Verificação se a cabeça da cobra encostou no corpo
        if (rastro[i].x == cabecax && rastro[i].y == cabecay) {
            velocidadex = velocidadey = 0
            rabo = 5
        }
    }
    //Movimentação da cobra
    rastro.push({x:cabecax, y:cabecay})
    //Mantém o rastro e a cauda da cobra do mesmo tamanho
    while(rastro.length > rabo) {
        rastro.shift()
    }
    //Aumentar a cauda da cobra ao comer a fruta e fruta recolocada randomicamente
    if (frutax == cabecax && frutay == cabecay)
        rabo++
        frutax = Math.floor(Math.random() * quantidadep)
        frutay = Math.floor(Math.random() * quantidadep)
    }        
}

//Movimentação através das teclas
function KeyPush(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37: //tecla left
            velocidadex = -vel
            velocidadey = 0                
            break;
        case 38: //tecla up
            velocidadex = 0
            velocidadey = -vel                
            break;
        case 39: //tecla right
            velocidadex = vel
            velocidadey = 0                
            break;
        case 40: //tecla down
            velocidadex = 0
            velocidadey = vel                
            break;
        default:
            break;
            //Para subir a velocidade é negativa, para subir positiva
    }

}
```

```html
<canvas id="stage" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta uma chaveta no if statement da fruta.

```
if (frutax == cabecax && frutay == cabecay) {
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda, era isso mesmo!